# Upper Hessenberg Form

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am given a matrix. I would like to reduce it to its upper Hessenberg Form. We are discussing eigenvalue computations in Numerical Analysis and the textbook just gives the algorithm for it without an example. So I was wondering if anyone knew of any textbook or an article or a forum where it is shown how to transform a given matrix $A$ into its upper Hessenberg form with as much detail as possible. Or if someone could show me the steps, that would be fantastic as well. The example that is given in the book is as follows. Thanks!

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  4 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
  2 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
  2 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Perform arnoldi iterations.

Comment: Will that transform the matrix into its upper Hessenberg form?

Comment: Yes. If you perform the iterations to full matrix order.

Comment: There are quite a few excellent books on numerical linear algebra, e.g., [Fundamentals of Matrix Computations](http://books.google.fr/books?id=xi5omWiQ-3kC&lpg=PP1&dq=matrix%20computations&hl=cs&pg=PR12#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Watkins or [Matrix Computations](http://books.google.fr/books?id=X5YfsuCWpxMC&lpg=PP1&dq=matrix%20computations&hl=cs&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Golub and Van Loan to name a few. Both cover reductions to Hessenberg and tridiagonal forms in detail.